# TrueCrypt mounting drive on network

Tags: truecrypt

My question is related to TrueCrypt drive created on a server. I want to mount this drive on few computers on network with write access. In order to do so, I installed TrueCrypt on a network computer and mounted the drive.

**Problem**

It mounts the drive after asking the password but triggers write error. In other words, it is read only.

**What I have tried so far**

I have looked in the documentation at truecrypt.com and it shows there are two methods of mounting

1. TrueCrypt Mounted Drive (Mounts drive on a local computer with read only access)
2. Unmounted Drive (Drive is mounted on the server and shared across the network)

**What I want**

Option 2 seems to be solving the problem with exception to it doesn't ask for password. It is same as any shared folder on network which makes it less secure. So is it possible to to mount drive on network with write access but after authenticating with TrueCrypt login credentials.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write to it locally ?

Comment: Yes, I can write when I mount drive on server (if that's what you mean by locally).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I have read (I haven't tried it myself) when you download the truecrypt file to your local machine, you should be able to mount it there and would be prompted for password. Once mounted, you should be able to write to or modify to your hearts content and then save to the encrypted volume you local machine. You will not be able to save the changes into the original server-based volume as that file is 'read only'. However, you should be able to save your modified volume to the server under a different file name.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

1. mounted the TrueCrypt Drive and a TrueCrypt-Container with VeraCrypt
2. created a windows (samba) and mac (afp) share of the drive and container with a password in the share settings (whatever software you use)

Mounting the container prevented it from being overwritten from some one else opening the container directly.